# How configure Ubuntu to suspend after inactivity based on time of day?

Tags: suspend, power-management, time, automation

I know we can configure Ubuntu to go to sleep after being inactive for "x" amount of time. But I want that to be based on time of day. 
Say, suspend computer if it has been inactive for 1 hour and it is past 0000 hours and before 0600 hours.

How to do so?